# Using custom negotiator and custom formatter in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

Here's my custom formatter which I want to use for "*application/x.product*" content type:

```
public class ProductFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public ProductFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x.product"));
        }
        public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            return false;
        }
        public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            var result = (type == typeof(Product) || type == typeof(IEnumerable<Product>));
            return result;
        }

        public override async Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            List<string> productStrings = new List<string>();
            IEnumerable<Product> products = value is Product ? new Product[] { (Product)value } : (IEnumerable<Product>)value;
            foreach (Product product in products)
            {
                productStrings.Add(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}",
                product.ProductID, product.Name, product.Price));
            }
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream);
            await writer.WriteAsync(string.Join(",", productStrings));
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Registered as:

```
config.Formatters.Add(new ProductFormatter());
```

I also have a custom negotiator (also registered):

```
public class CustomNegotiator : DefaultContentNegotiator
    {
        public override ContentNegotiationResult Negotiate(Type type,
        HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters)
        {
            // look for an appropriate formatter
            MediaTypeFormatter formatter = null;
            foreach(var f in formatters)
            {
                var mediaType = f.SupportedMediaTypes.Where(mt => mt.MediaType == "application/x.product").SingleOrDefault();
                if (mediaType != null)
                {
                    formatter = f;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (request.Headers.UserAgent.Where(x => x.Product != null
            && x.Product.Name.ToLower().Equals("chrome")).Count() > 0 && formatter != null)
            {
                // if client is chrome then return superproduct and use custom formatter for it
                return new ContentNegotiationResult(formatter,
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x.product")
                );
            }
            else
            {
                return base.Negotiate(type, request, formatters);
            }
        }
    }
```

I also want to use this with *application/x.product* when a client is Google Chrome.

Is my way of searching an appropriate formatter okay, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ProductFormatter**

The `WriteToStreamAsync()` method could be improved by using the `using` keyword with the `StreamWriter`. By using `using` the flushing and disposing of the stream is done automatically.

Having a `string.Format()` like it is used together with the `string.Join()` is suboptimal. You should better add the product details to the `List<string>` and let the `string.Join()` to the work.

Implementing this points will lead to

```
public override async Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
{
    List<string> productStrings = new List<string>();
    IEnumerable<Product> products = value is Product ? new Product[] { (Product)value } : (IEnumerable<Product>)value;
    foreach (Product product in products)
    {
        productStrings.Add(product.ProductID);
        productStrings.Add(product.Name);
        productStrings.Add(product.Price);
    } 

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
    {
        await writer.WriteAsync(string.Join(",", productStrings));
    }
}
```

You should also take into account that `object value` could be `null`. Assuming that it is an `IEnumerable<Product>` if it isn't a `Product` type is suboptimal.

---

**CustomNegotiator**

The retrieving of the formatter should be extracted to a separate method otherwise the `Negotiate()` method would do to many things and would violate the single responsibility principle.

The way how you are doing the search is ok, but could be improved by extracting the `"application/x.product"` to a class constant.

This `if`

> ```
> if (request.Headers.UserAgent.Where(x => x.Product != null
> && x.Product.Name.ToLower().Equals("chrome")).Count() > 0 && formatter != null)
> ```

should be improved by first checking if `formatter != null` and to use `Any()` instead of `Count() > 0`. By using `Count() > 0` all of the items will be iterated over and counted. Using `Any()` will iterate only until any item is found for which the condition is true. Instead of `x.Product.Name.ToLower().Equals("chrome")` you should use the overloaded [`Equals()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which takes a `StringComparision` enum as second parameter. This buyes you two things. The first is the call to `ToLower()` isn't needed anymore and the second is that your code will pass the [turkey test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).

Implementing this points will lead to

```
private const string mediaType = "application/x.product";
private MediaTypeFormatter FindFormatter(IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters)
{

    foreach (var formatter in formatters)
    {
        var foundMediaType = formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Where(mt => mt.MediaType == mediaType).SingleOrDefault();
        if (foundMediaType != null)
        {
            return formatter;
        }
    }

    return null;
}  

public class CustomNegotiator : DefaultContentNegotiator
{
    public override ContentNegotiationResult Negotiate(Type type,
                HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters)
    {

        var formatter = FindFormatter(formatters);

        if (formatter != null && request.Headers.UserAgent.Any(x => x.Product != null
                                 && x.Product.Name.Equals("chrome", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
            // if client is chrome then return superproduct and use custom formatter for it
            return new ContentNegotiationResult(formatter,
                            new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaType));
        }
        else
        {
            return base.Negotiate(type, request, formatters);
        }
    }
}
```